# Create multiple connections using netcat and send continuous traffic through each netcat connection

Tags: bash, shell, connection, netcat, traffic

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 1000`;
do
echo sahil | nc -v 10.33.0.32 4050 &
#sleep 1
done
```

Currently I'm albe to create 1000 nc connections, each connection is running as a process. Now I want all these 1000 connections to send traffic continuously.
**Need a script through which I can create multiple connections(more than 1000 conns) using netcat and also send traffic continuously through each connection.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `echo sahil` with `dd if=/dev/urandom | base64` if you need a bunch of random data, otherwise `dd if=/dev/zero` could also work.

I think that technically answers your question, but if you are looking to perform a loadtest on a server, there are many tools such as [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html), or [Locust](https://locust.io/), which will make that much easier.

Comment: Thanks, I needed random data